A pre 2000s cartoon in fantasy setting featuring anthropomorphic characters
I remember watching a cartoon, back in the late 90s which features anthropomorphic characters set in medieval or fantasy setting. I don't remember much from the show. I am not even 100% sure I didn't dream of it (it's been a long time ago and I only saw a fragment of a single episode and I was a kid back then!). Anyhow, a list of things I remember:

Anthropomorphic characters of different species
There were knights and peasants so the setting was some kind of medieval
Not sure if vanilla or magical one, though, but I don't recall seeing any wizards or other magical things
I watched it in late 90s, maybe early 2000s and I seem to recall it looked like 80s-90s cartoon
I saw it in a Polish TV station but I am certain it was not a Polish production
It looked like a western animation, I'd wager a guess it was more of a US production than French
No idea about the language
It wasn't a typical monster of the week (TV Tropes warning!) series, there was an overarching plot and a cliffhanger at the end of the episode
The plot was pretty serious, at least for a cartoon of that time

With that being said, I saw it 15 years ago when I was 8-12 years old so some things might be fuzzy. Since then I've tried to look for it multiple times but never managed to locate it myself

A lot of it sounds like Redwall.

It started airing in 1999;
Its characters were different animal species in a medieval setting;
There was an overarching plot (each season was based on a different Redwall book)
Western animation in English;
It was a somewhat serious cartoon.

Here's are a few minutes from the first episode:




Holy wow, it IS that cartoon! After all these years I was seriously thinking I dreamed it up (because it wouldn't be the first dream-experience I have confused with). Thank you!
